# Cannot find module 'enquire.js' from 'slider.js'

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am using Antd with React, Jest and Enzyme. While testing simple shallow rendering I am getting error

"Cannot find module 'enquire.js' from 'slider.js'"

at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules\jest-resolve\build\index.js:151:17

at Object. (node_modules\react-slick\lib\slider.js:37:38)

at Object. (node_modules\react-slick\lib\index.js:3:18)[index file, test file and Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obq1O.jpg)

Comment: Please post the code you have so far in here, instead of linking to an image. Your package.json would be interesting as well.

Comment: Hi, I added required codes to this repo.

index.js: https://github.com/madHEYsia/repolink/blob/master/index.js
index.test.js: https://github.com/madHEYsia/repolink/blob/master/index.test.js
package.json: https://github.com/madHEYsia/repolink/blob/master/package.json

Hope I am clear at my end

Comment: Hey, I got answer here(https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/6317), 

thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just want to copy the solution for this which where given here: https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/6317

> For npm: rm -rf node_modules && npm install
>
> For yarn: yarn upgrade

Answer (score 0):

I found a very short way of above, just try this :

```
npm i enquire-js@0.1.0
```

> 0.1.0 depend on version come out